# Search and replace Greek letters in notebook

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often use Greek letters in my calculations. Is there any way, to replace all occurrences of say ø with µ? From a computational/mathematical standpoint, it makes no difference what the variable name is. But sometimes, we are conditioned to use certain variables and become used to them. So if I happen to use an odd variable and need to share my notebook with a colleague, I'd like to change the variable before sending it. Is there an efficient way to search and replace Greek letters in mma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Mathematica 7 or later, you can use the "Find" dialog to do this.  Type `\[Phi]` as the search string and `\[Mu]` as the replacement string.  This may also work in Mathematica 6 or earlier, but I don't have those versions at hand at the moment to try it.

See the "Listing of Named Characters" in the Mathematica help for the escape codes that you can use.

Comment: Out or curiosity, what are the characters in question?  WReach is using `\[Phi]` for something that looks like `\[OSlash]` in my browser, although `\[OSlash]` isn't really a Greek character, so he's probably right.

Comment: Thanks. I've been using the `escape-letter-escape` sequence for quite a while that I forgot that `\[Mu]` has a capital `M`. I tried `\[mu]` and when that didn't work, I posted here.

Comment: @Brett Champion: You're right, it's not exactly `phi` although that is what I intended it to be. I was lazy and just used `Option-O` on my mac which produces that character. I think it's the `o-slash` letter present in all the Nordic languages.

Answer (score 2):

The find and replace dialog should work for this.

Assuming version 8, you can either use long names (`\[OSlash]`) to input the names, or shortcuts (*shift-esc o / shift-esc*).

(*shift-esc* being necessary because plain old *esc* in the find dialog will dismiss the dialog.)

In earlier versions the long name method should work.  (The long name won't collapse into the character, but after finding/replacing it's all fine.)

Answer (score 1):

In mma7, one possibility that is sometimes handy is  `Use Selection for Find`.  That is, select the greek letter (or whatever you want to replace), then (from the EDIT menu) -> Find -> Use Selection for Find.

When the Search/Replace dialog box is now invoked, the \ [phi] (for example) will be in the Find dialog box. On a Macintosh, the shortcut is command E (followed by command F). Also works for\ [CapitalDelta] etc.